# Inner query is difficult to write

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

`customer` with `schema_id`

Schema table has: `schema_id, period, amt, updated_date`

I need to take join of customer and schema but only retrieve the latest record joined and not the others.

```
customer table

cust_id  name schema_id
1        ABC  1
```

Schema table

```
schema_id  period amt updated_date
1          1      100  2010-4-1
1          2      150  2011-4-1
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the `max(updated_date)` for each `schema_id`, then you can use an subquery:

```
select c.cust_id, c.name, c.schema_id, s.period, s.amt, s.updated_date
from customer c
inner join
(
  select s1.schema_id, s1.period, s1.amt, s1.updated_date
  from `schemas` s1
  inner join 
  (
    select schema_id, max(updated_date) MaxDate
    from `schemas`
    group by schema_id
  ) s2
    on s1.schema_id = s2.schema_id
    and s1.updated_date = s2.maxdate
) s
  on c.schema_id = s.schema_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa2c3/5)

The subquery is then used in a join back to your table to return the rows that have the matching date and schema_id.

Comment: @AbhijitShelar What do you mean `t1` does not have `updated_date`?  The `updated_date` is in your table.  This is doing a self-join to get the rows for each `schema_id` and `max(updated_date)`.

Comment: first table only has schema_id as one of column

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you need to take lastest register of the "schema".

I think you need to use max() function. So, try the query below:

```
select *
from customer c,
     schema s
where c.schema_id = s.schema_id
  and s.updated_date = ( select max(s2.updated_date)     
                         from schema s2
                         where s2.schema_id = s.schema_id
                       )
```

Regards!

Edmilton

Comment: Please, always explicitly specify your joins, don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause).  Among other things, it makes reasoning about certain join conditions extremely difficult.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse oh yes, absolutely. I might have written a bit about this: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip Clockwork-Muse and @aaron-bertrand. But I think it's subjective! BTW, I'll read about that, including Aaron's post!

Comment: @Edmilton I don't think it is all that subjective in 2013. Since the old-style outer join is deprecated, how would you propose to add, say, a left join to this query? Do you not find it easier to separate filter criteria from join criteria and explicitly state your intent, never mind avoid an accidental cross join?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Really. It makes sense!
I make a mix. I use old-style for 'inner join'. If I need to use left/right join, I use new-style (no so new).
This way always worked for me and others teams that I've participated, but, I promess, I'll read more about that. =)
Maybe I've been wrong all that time!
Thank you!

Comment: IMHO explicit is always better. Even if there were no downsides to being implicit, what does it save you aside from a few keystrokes?